# Why is rendering this SVG map crashing my browser?

Tags: d3.js, gis, topojson

I'm trying to make a drought map with D3 (and topojson), using [this shapefile](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/shapefiles_combined/2013/usdm130521m.zip).

I've converted it to both GeoJSON and topojson, but in either case, trying to render causes the browser to hang and CPU for that tab to hit 100% or higher.

I can render larger files, like all [US counties](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json), and I can render the file using Mapnik or TileMill. But in the browser, it dies.

[Here's the relevant code](https://gist.github.com/eyeseast/5647277).

```
var map = d3.select('#map').append('svg')
    .style('width', width)
    .style('height', height);

var albers = d3.geo.albersUsa();

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(albers);

d3.json(urls.drought, function(err, data) {

    var drought = window.drought = topojson.feature(data, data.objects.usdm130521);

    map.selectAll('path')
        .data(drought.features)
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('d', path);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out. As the [USDM site says](http://droughtmonitor.unl.edu/metadata.htm), "The files have been projected to the USA Contiguous Albers Equal Area Conic projection."

It turns out, this is a problem, though I don't fully understand it. I converted it to `EPSG: 4326` using `ogr2ogr`:

```
$ ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 usdm130521-projected.shp usdm130521.shp
```

And it rendered. Quick, too.

Mike Bostock wrote more about projecting topojson [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5557726).